# Regex for replacing multiple spaces and dashes with or without spaces

Tags: regex

I can do this with two separate regex passes, but this is already slow and doing two doesn't help, so I want to be able to do it in one pass.

I want to:

- replace multiple spaces with one space
- replace a dash (hyphen) with a space

However, if the dash has a space on either side of it then the dash and any spaces either side to be replaced with just one space.

As an example:

```
a - b c-d e -f g- h i  - j k -  l m  -  n
```

must end up like

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n
```

I have tried things like this:

```
\s+| - | -|- |-
```

but that doesn't work:

```
a  b c d e  f g h i  j k   l m   n
```

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: Also what should happen if you have multiple dashes?

Comment: multiple dashes to be treated as if they were one dash, so replaced by one space

Comment: I'm user javascript style regex

Comment: Also you use `\s+` but ` - `.  What is the requirement for whitespace other than the space character? (tabulator being the most common).

Comment: space character does not work with all regex engines, so have got into the habit of using \s

Comment: Which engines fails on the space character?

Comment: Now you're asking - don't remember off the top of my head, just got into that habit since I discovered it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the following regexp to match multiple spaces or dashes;

```
[\s-]+
```

Replace with a single space.

Comment: @Graham it works because you are treating spaces and hyphens the same, ie. if you have a sequence containing spaces and hyphens you don't care what is what - The whole sequence should be replaced with a single space.  So you it sets a character group that is whitespace pluss the hyphen and looks for instances where that occurs.

Comment: @Graham you could simply ask the question as "How to replace one or more dashes or spaces with a space?"

Answer (score 3):

`[\s-]+` with a global '**g**' modifier and replace with one single space.
See [here](http://regex101.com/r/lD2hQ8/1)

Answer (score 1):

**Regex:**

```
(?:\s*-\s*)+|\s{2,}
```

REplacement string:

```
<space>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iZ6kO1/5)

Comment: Not sure this works with strings such as `a   a   b - a` where more than one space occurs with no hyphen between letters...

Comment: This does not replace multiple spaces if there are no hyphens.

Comment: doesn't deal with multiple dashes